# Is there an advantage to using static global work variables?

Tags: java

This may be picking at nits, but are there any time/memory efficiencies in using global static fields for throwaway work variables?  Given the trivial example:

```
class theClass {

private static GregorianCalendar wkCal;
private static int wkTimes1;
private static int wkTimes2;
private static int wkTimes3;
private static StringBuilder wkSb = new StringBuilder();

void aMethod(int n) {
    wkTimes1 = n * 1;
    wkTimes2 = n * 2;
    wkTimes3 = n * 3;
    wkCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    wkSb.setLength(0);
    wkSb.append("A string"); 
    // And so on...
}
}
```

This snippet has the potential to be instantiated many times (> 3000) and aMethod being used many times per instantiation. Additionally, the wk prefixed fields will be used in other methods and are designed to hold temporary values used only for intermediate calculations.

The way I see it, if you heed the usual caveats about using global variables, this saves memory and time.

Comment: Is this code running on a single thread? If it is, this is fine. If your code will change in the future to support threading, this is not fine.

Comment: The "usual caveats about using global variables" are that they're evil, risky, untestable, and you _shouldn't use them._  (But no, they don't give you efficiency advantages over local variables.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're instantiating it 3000 times (which isn't much), and there's ever more than one at a time, you're begging for a nice non-deterministic race condition. Why not just use locals and eliminate all doubt?

Locals go away when the method is done running, unlike an instance variable which will be GCed at an indeterminate amount of time in the future.

Comment: I'd agree that 3000 executions isn't much at all, especially on a modern multi-core system. If the method does take a long time (database access perhaps) then the overhead of instantiating/not instantiating a handful of variables will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

In general, static variables are slower to access than instance fields (or at least no faster), and way, way slower than local variables.  The only two reasons for statics are if you need some class-wide "memory" of prior events, or if you have some common (basically read-only) object (such as a calendar object) that is accessed repeatedly by methods in the class.

It would be really inefficient to use a static for an int or some other scalar that could just as well be a local variable.

It's also quite dangerous to use a static for a highly mutable object such as a StringBuilder.  Calling from methodA to methodB you could unexpectedly both use the same object, with bad results.  (Not to mention the problems with threaded apps.)

(It should be pointed out that it costs essentially nothing to allocate a local variable -- either a scaler int/float/whatever, or an object reference.  And it costs very little to add an instance field -- the `new` time initialization is just the time to zero the space (which is basically the way it comes from heap anyway).)

Answer (score 0):

The others have suggested and I will agree that it will make a negligible difference in speed and is very bad form that will bite you or a co-worker when you least expect it.

However, if you're not convinced then create a microbenchmark to prove that there is little to no difference between implementations. It should be an easy matter to create two different versions of the method and then time 100,000 or 10,000,000 executions of the function with random values of n and see how long each one takes.